# Multi-target solution builder

Tags: python, msbuild, build-process

[An opensource project](https://github.com/unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp) currently uses CMake to generate project files for multiple versions of Visual Studio.

I noticed that Node uses python script to do a similar thing but is more elegant since the output of the tool doesn't hardcode directory paths into those project files.  However the current node setup only seems to support 2010 and 2012.  The node documentation doesn't say what the build tools are just "The build tools distributed with Node run on python."

The batch file included with Node calls python configure, but doing a search on that returns a zillion unrelated results.

I was wondering if this tool/script is

- an open source project with website, documentation, etc.
- extensible to earlier versions of VS (2003 onwards).

What I am looking to do is produce a bunch of solutions and projects that should just work straight out the box and not be tied to a particular dev's directory layout like CMake does. Also the script allows me to easily update multiple scripts if a file gets added or removed.

Comment: `configure` python package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/configure/0.5

Comment: Is there any instruction on using it for building MSVC projects?  Do you know of any other open source projects that do the same I could use for 'inspiration'?

Comment: I have no idea. I just searched `configure` on PyPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Node uses [GYP](http://code.google.com/p/gyp/) to generate it's project files. I had a quick play earlier and seems fairly easy to use.